# Update value in c# dictionary object if value is something

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to update value in c# dictionary object if value is something.

```
Dictionary<string, int> Section = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
            {"a", 1},
            {"b", 0},
            {"c", 2},
            {"d", 0},
            {"e", 0},
            {"f", 0},
};
```

1. I want to loop through Section object and if value= 2 i want to set it to 1
2. I want to set the value = 1 from 4th element till end.(i.e, from "d" to "f")

Thanks,

Praveen

I have tried,

```
foreach(var item in Section)
{
   if(item.value == 2)
   {
     item.value == 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - I want to loop through Section object and if value= 2 i want to set it to 1

You can look through the Dictionary items, and change the value as needed.

This could be something like:

```
var itemsToEdit = Section.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 2).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
foreach(var item in itemsToEdit)
     Section[item] = 1;
```

> - I want to set the value = 1 from 4th element till end.(i.e, from "d" to "f")

Realize that, once you put the values in a dictionary, they lose all ordering.  A Dictionary is inherently an unordered collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection within a `foreach`.

However, you can loop through a derived collection! Note the `ToList()` to create a separate collection (the `Where()` just wraps the original collection):

```
foreach (var item in Section.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 2).ToList())
{
    Section[item.Key] = 1;
}
```

Second, we first order the list, then skip the first three elements to get the fourth element onward:

```
foreach (var item in Section.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Skip(3).ToList())
{
    Section[item.Key] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st:

```
foreach (var key in Section.Where(item => item.Value == 2).Select(item => item.Key).ToList())
{
    Section[key] = 1;
}
```

2nd:

```
foreach (var key in Section.Keys.Where(k=>String.Compare(k, "d", StringComparison.Ordinal)>=0).ToList())
{
    Section[key] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Like @Reed said once you put the values in a dictionary, they lose all ordering. A Dictionary is inherently an unordered collection. So, i thing i need find individual element and set the values.

Comment: You can use an [Ordered Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) if you need to preserve order.  It won't be strongly typed, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
foreach (int value in Section.Values) {

  if ((index > 3) || (value == 2)) { 
    Section[index] = 1; 
  }

  index++;
}
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i < Section.Count; i++) {
  if ((i > 3) || (Section[i] == 2)) {
    Section[i] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that your solution will do what you expects. You cannot assume that the `.Values` collection will be returned ordered by the key, and you might end up updating `Section[index] = 1` based on `value == 2` where `value` is bound to another index.

Comment: @faester "The order of the values in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection returned by the Keys property."  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx.  So if the indexer truly returns a different order we can solve it by using the key instead (though it is more cumbersome).  Or we can use the alternate `for` loop.

Comment: Hey Peter - Thanks :) Then the only problem may be if the keys are always incremented by one.